# SQL Count depending on certain conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables.

One have userid and email (users table). The other have payments information (payments table) from the userid in users.

```
users
+--------+------------+
| Userid |    Name    |
+--------+------------+
|      1 | Alex T     |
|      2 | Jeremy T   |
|      3 | Frederic A |
+--------+------------+

payments
+--------+-----------+------------+----------+
| Userid | ValuePaid | PaidMonths | Refunded |
+--------+-----------+------------+----------+
|      1 |         1 |         12 | null     |
|      1 |        20 |         12 | null     |
|      1 |        20 |         12 | null     |
|      1 |        20 |          1 | null     |
|      2 |         1 |          1 | null     |
|      2 |        20 |         12 | 1        |
|      2 |        20 |         12 | null     |
|      2 |        20 |          1 | null     |
|      3 |         1 |         12 | null     |
|      3 |        20 |          1 | 1        |
|      3 |        20 |          1 | null     |
+--------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

I want to count the PaidMonths taking in consideration the following rules:

- If ValuePaid < 10 PaidMonths should be = 0.23 (even if in the column the value seen is any other mumber).
- If Refund=1 the PaidMonths should be = 0.

Based on this when i join both tables by userid, and sum the PaidMonths based in the previousrules, i expect to see as result:

```
+--------+------------+------------+
| userid |    Name    | paidMonths |
+--------+------------+------------+
|      1 | Alex T     | 25.23      |
|      2 | Jeremy T   | 13.23      |
|      3 | Frederic A | 1.23       |
+--------+------------+------------+
```

Can you help me to achieve this in the most elegant way? Should a temporary table be used?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: What if Valuepaid < 10 and Refund=1?

Comment: That doesn't happen, but it would be 0. Ty stu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gives your desired results, using `apply` with `case expression` to map your values:

```
select u.UserID, u.Name, Sum(pm) PaidMonths
from users u join payments p on p.userid=u.userid
cross apply (values(
    case 
      when valuepaid <10 then 0.23
      when Refunded=1 then 0
    else PaidMonths end
))x(pm)
group by u.UserID, u.Name
```

See [Working Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=a2b93f9eab65a9c937bbd3b4f6d50468)

Comment: This is amazing! It worked. I would never get there.

Comment: Question, where do you learn advanced stuff like this? I never saw this cross apply values before

Comment: @UcanDoIt - Cross apply is SQL Server's syntax for what is called a `lateral join`, it's part of the ANSI SQL standard and supported by almost all RDBMS platforms. It often lends itself to a "clean" solution but is not "required".

Comment: how can i learn more about this fancy stuff? there is any good advanced ms sql tutorial in youtube, or any other place that you recomment?

Comment: We learn by doing - you've just learned something new by asking on Stack Overflow, keep looking at new questions and try to answer some if you can, look at others' answers, `cross apply` and `values` usually appear in various solutions daily.

Comment: thanks so much @stu.  apart from SQL what other dev languanges you dominate?